# android webview: loadUrl("javascript:(function() { ... }") vs evaluateJavascript(...)

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

As I understand, there are two ways to inject **JS** execution onto current page in Android `WebView`.

I'm wondering if there are pros/cons of one over the other except that:

```
 WebView.evaluateJavascript(...)
```

provides a call back?

Answer (score 0):

One more advantage is evaluateJavascript() is asynchronous. A situation in which some apps make this mistake is while waiting for a JavaScript callback. For example, do not use code like this:

```
// This code is BAD and will block the UI thread
webView.loadUrl("javascript:fn()");
while(result == null) {
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Instead we need to use, evaluateJavascript(), to run JavaScript asynchronously.